# How to group data in a Dataframe if they are of the same flow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

row_1 = pd.Series({'Address A': 3647,
                   'Address B': 555,
                   'Total Delay': 1.2})
row_2 = pd.Series({'Address A': 555,
                   'Address B': 3647,
                   'Total Delay': 2.1})
row_3 = pd.Series({'Address A': 4567,
                   'Address B': 555,
                   'Total Delay': 0.6})
df = pd.DataFrame([row_1, row_2, row_3], index = [1, 2, 3])
df.head()

output:

    Address A   Address B   Total Delay                         
1   3647        555         1.2
2   555         3647        2.1
3   4567        555         0.6
```

Suppose I have the above Dataframe, how can I group 1 and 2 as [3647 555] if they are the same across the rows and add the their total delay to 3.3, giving me a new Dataframe.

I have to do this for 50,000 more data.

```
    Address A   Address B   Total Delay                         
1   3647        555         3.3
3   4567        555         0.6
```

Comment: What is the criteria ? that A and B are same but inverted ?  Also give the code for a reproducible problem, create a small datafram with these data please

Comment: Basically imagine A is the source address and B is the destination address and in row 1 A is Communicating with B and in row 2 B is communicating with A. Hence, they are apart of the same flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we sort `Address A` and `Address B` over the index axis (per row) with `np.sort`. Then we `GroupBy` on these columns and use `sum` + `first`:

```
cols = ['Address B', 'Address A']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols])

dfg = df.groupby(cols).agg({'No.':'first',
                            'Total Delay':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

```
   Address A  Address B  No.  Total Delay
0       3647        555    1         3.30
1       4567        555    3         0.60
```

---

If you want the columns in that exact order, use `DataFrame.reindex`:

```
dfg = dfg.reindex(df.columns, axis='columns')
```

```
   No.  Address A  Address B  Total Delay
0    1       3647        555         3.30
1    3       4567        555         0.60
```